# how to use IF count in a data.frame column the cells wiht missing value(NA)?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame object named "selPOGs2". In this data.frame I'm adding one column "GeneID". After I transform the data.frame to character, I add data in the "GeneID" column. These data are returned from a query to a database. If no answer is found in the database, then in the corresponding cell in GeneID column a NA is placed.
The column looks something like this:

> Blockquote

```
   GeneID
```

1. NA
2. NA
3. 14297062
4. 14006762
5. 11538038

> Blockquote

I want to count the number of times the NA is found in the GeneID column. 
I wrote the following code:

```
  #convert selPOGs2 from factor to character (to make is is really character and not factor)
  selPOGs2 <- data.frame(lapply(selPOGs2, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  a=0; is.numeric(a)
  for(c in selPOGs2[,1])
  {b <- as.character(c) 
      if(b[1]== NA_character_) 
      {  a=a+1   }
      else {a=a}
  }
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in if (b[1] == NA_character_) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I get the same error regardless if I compare b[1] with "14297062" or with any other "...".

If I comment the code related to IF , the value for c or for b[1] is reported as "14297062", e.g.

```
      a=0; is.numeric(a)
      for(c in selPOGs2[,1])
      {b <- as.character(c) 
          #if(b[1]== NA_character_) 
          #{  a=a+1   }
          #else {a=a}
      }
```

However, as soon as un-comment the IF lines , the value for c or b[1] is reported as NA_character_.

If I use

```
 a=0; is.numeric(a)
  for(c in selPOGs2[,1])
  {b <- as.character(c) 
      if(1==1) 
  }
```

the again the value for c or for b[1] is reported as "14297062", e.g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
sum(is.na(selPOGs2$GeneID))
```

to count the `NA`s.

Comment: Maybe you can help me further. Lets assume that I don't want to know the number of NA, but rather the number of "14297062" occurrences. Any idea what's wrong whit my code?

Comment: @CLM `sum(selPOGs2$GeneID == "14297062")`

Comment: actually, it works only if I add the following argument - na.rm = TRUE, e.g. sum(selPOGs2$GeneID == "14297062", na.rm = TRUE); it the argument is not set TRUE, than it returns NA instead of the number of occurrences

Comment: @CLM Right. It should be `sum(na.omit(selPOGs2$GeneID) == "14297062")`